# Tracking the location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I got the current location latitude and longitude while giving on in a switch button in android and displaying the location in google map. But I need the latitude and longitude changes automatically wherever the device moves and the location on the map should change with respect to the position. How is it possible? Can anyone give me a way?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient).
You can use `requestLocationUpdates(...)` to get the users position in a given intervall.
You can find more Info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

But honestly you could have find the answer on your own if you googled a bit.